# ruby on rails file download binary files from the database and provide a link

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubyzip

I have 3 files in my mysql database. 2 of them is of type 'text' and 1 is 'longblob'.

```
|username| |pem      | |key       | |cert              |

|test1   | |some text| |Some text | | Some binary text |

|test2   | |some text| |Some text | | Some binary text |
```

I can query them and have an array ActiveRecord Relation object
in the @user_files variable.

Now, I want to create the 3 files filename1.pem, filename1.key, filename1.cert for each user and provide them as a link for download.

Something like:

```
<%- @user_files.each do |user_info| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'Download Files', download_path(user_info) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Here is what I had in my mind so far in my controller:

```
 def download(user_file)
    temp = Tempfile.new("temp-filename-#{Time.now}")
    Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(temp.path) do |z|
      z.put_next_entry("some_name.pem")
      z.print IO.read(user_file.pem)
      z.put_next_entry("some_name.key")
      z.print IO.read(user_file.key)
      z.put_next_entry("some_name.cert")
      z.print IO.read(user_file.cert)
     end
     send_file temp.path, :type => 'application/octet-stream', :filename => "some_name.zip"
    temp.close  
 end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
app/controllers/my_controller.rb:16:in `download'
```

My routes is as follows:

```
get 'download' => 'my_controller#download', as: :download
```

My first question is if this is the right approach and will it even work?
I would appreciate it if someone could guide me to a cleaner approach for my requirement.

EDIT: I updated to use params

<%= link_to 'Download Files, download_path(user_info) %>

```
def download
  user_info = params[:id]
  #remaining code
end
```

Also get this error now afte rthe route update suggested in the answer:

```
No route matches [GET] "/download/415"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller action must not have any arguments. Everything you would like to pass to your controller action is accessed by `params` variable which is a `Hash` ([HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) actually). So that, your `download` action might look like:

```
 def download
    user_file = params[:id]
    temp = Tempfile.new("temp-filename-#{Time.now}")
    Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(temp.path) do |z|
      z.put_next_entry("some_name.pem")
      z.print IO.read(user_file.pem)
      z.put_next_entry("some_name.key")
      z.print IO.read(user_file.key)
      z.put_next_entry("some_name.cert")
      z.print IO.read(user_file.cert)
     end
     send_file temp.path, :type => 'application/octet-stream', :filename => "some_name.zip"
    temp.close  
 end
```

Also, change your route into:

```
get 'download/:id' => 'my_controller#download', as: :download
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the first error. But i get nil object if I pass it as a param to the controller.

Comment: I've changed my answer slightly.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. see my edit. But i am still running into errors. I dont think your route suggestion makes sense in my use case, does it?

Comment: Well, if you don't like `:id`, you can call it whatever you want. You do need however pass a param to `download` action to get the user info. I tempted to test suggested route via `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.download_path(212)` and it gets proper route, i.e. `/download/212`.

Comment: so if your id is 212, wouldn't it attempt 212.pem, 212.cert instead of the actual user_info  object passed in? I cannot get the user_info through that id. that user_info is retrieved through an external service

Comment: Well, I don't know all the details from question you've provided. However, if you're iterating through `@user_files`, I guess each `user_info` should be `user_file`. If so, you have to fetch given user file by simply `user_file = UserFile.find params[:id]` (it depends how the model is called). With that, you have all needed context in your `download` method and now you can build appropriate logic.

Comment: sorry blelump. I should have been clear. the @user_file retrieves its information by doing multiple joins across 2 different databases. That's the reason I cannot do a simple 'id' search and get results back. That's why I wanted to pass the whole object to the download action instead of just the id initially.

Comment: Ok, I see. You can't pass an instance of an object. This is not just a method invocation, but sending new request to your web server. Request does not know anything about your server or its logic, it just contains the essential data to pass it through Rack, then controller etc. In short, it is not trivial, but what's important here, what you can put into your controller is any data that can be serialized in any manner. So that, having a link, it is usual to pass an id of an object and instantiate it later in controller.

Comment: blelump, thanks for the explanation. I am updating my model to make your suggestion work.